This is my first time using pyspark and I'm having issues while using the structured-streaming
This is my current code since there were many errors I thought let's run a basic code first but I am having this error
# Current Code
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
from pyspark.sql.functions import split

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("StructuredNetworkWordCount") \
    .getOrCreate()

lines = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("socket") \
    .option("host", "localhost") \
    .option("port", 9999) \
    .load()

words = lines.select(
   explode(
       split(lines.value, " ")
   ).alias("word")
)

wordCounts = words.groupBy("word").count()

query = wordCounts \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode("complete") \
    .format("console") \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()

#Error
StreamingQueryException: [STREAM_FAILED] Query [id = 3e19a3c3-4e4e-4da6-9ed0-f9e8a6119894, runId = 25218498-e228-4954-a200-8e2df9accaec] terminated with exception: 'boolean org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(java.lang.String, int)'

I tried changing the winutils.exe file for the hadoop bin folder
I tried using the code directly from the pyspark documentation thinking it could work
But nothing seems to work
I have resolved many errors but this doesn't seem to be solved

You can test if this code works. https://stackoverflow.com/a/78399397/3238085 It uses socket as you are.
